# Empty Context String Warning

Tags: java, jetty

I try to configure a jetty context (programmatically) for using a servlet serving the root context.

For the context path I set "/" and for the servlet mapping "/*". This works exactly the way I want it to but Jetty is complaining (warning) about the context path ending with '/'. When I set the context path to "" (empty string), it results in the warning about an empty string.

The [documentation section of Jetty](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/SetContextPathto_/) about this issue states:

> Be aware
>   Java Servlet Specification 2.5 discourages an empty context path string, and Java Servlet Specification 3.0 effectively forbids it.

The portion of the Jetty source is:

```
public void setContextPath(String contextPath)
    {
    if (contextPath == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("null contextPath");

    if (contextPath.endsWith("/*"))
    {
        LOG.warn(this+" contextPath ends with /*");
        contextPath=contextPath.substring(0,contextPath.length()-2);
    }
    else if (contextPath.endsWith("/"))
    {
        LOG.warn(this+" contextPath ends with /");
        contextPath=contextPath.substring(0,contextPath.length()-1);
    }

    if (contextPath.length()==0)
    {
        LOG.warn("Empty contextPath");
        contextPath="/";
    }

    _contextPath = contextPath;

    if (getServer() != null && (getServer().isStarting() || getServer().isStarted()))
    {
        Handler[] contextCollections = getServer().getChildHandlersByClass(ContextHandlerCollection.class);
        for (int h = 0; contextCollections != null && h < contextCollections.length; h++)
            ((ContextHandlerCollection)contextCollections[h]).mapContexts();
    }
}
```

So the question is, what context path should I set in order to map to the root of the context. Currently everything works fine but having a forbidden context path setting by specification or a Jetty warning, I guess I need something different.

Comment: Would be bad style :)

Comment: Nope I have 15 years of Java experience being around since 1998 :).

Comment: But its a embedded Jetty for testing purpose. And every test this warning comes up since I stop and restart the server (takes 15ms by the way) this comes up. So it is disturbing for me checking for errors in the log and see this warning coming up every time... .

Comment: Well, I've been around just as long as you have, yet I have no problems ignoring warnings I know are non-essential. Must be a personality thing.

Comment: @MartinKersten I am facing some issue. It is showing "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null contextPath" .
Can you please help. I am unable to find where I am doing the mistake.
my application is on dropwizard framework with jetty server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to add a bug request for this after I noticed (thanks @Ozan!) that "/" is used in the case of setting the context path to "". So I thought it was a bug and yes it is. A [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=417730) already exists for this issue and it was fixed in 9.0.6 which is available since 2013 Sep 30. So I just upgraded the jetty version and the warning is now gone.

The Jetty code now checks if the length of the path is greater 1:

```
public void setContextPath(String contextPath)
{
    if (contextPath == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("null contextPath");

    if (contextPath.endsWith("/*"))
    {
        LOG.warn(this+" contextPath ends with /*");
        contextPath=contextPath.substring(0,contextPath.length()-2);
    }
    else if (contextPath.length()>1 && contextPath.endsWith("/"))
    {
        LOG.warn(this+" contextPath ends with /");
        contextPath=contextPath.substring(0,contextPath.length()-1);
    }

    if (contextPath.length()==0)
    {
        LOG.warn("Empty contextPath");
        contextPath="/";
    }

    _contextPath = contextPath;

    if (getServer() != null && (getServer().isStarting() || getServer().isStarted()))
    {
        Handler[] contextCollections = getServer().getChildHandlersByClass(ContextHandlerCollection.class);
        for (int h = 0; contextCollections != null && h < contextCollections.length; h++)
            ((ContextHandlerCollection)contextCollections[h]).mapContexts();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The docs says that

> The context path is the prefix of a URL path that is used to select
>   the context(s) to which an incoming request is passed. Typically a URL
>   in a Java servlet server is of the format
>   http://hostname.com/contextPath/servletPath/pathInfo, where each of
>   the path elements can be zero or more / separated elements. **If there
>   is no context path, the context is referred to as the root context.
>   The root context must be configured as "/" but is reported as the
>   empty string by the servlet API getContextPath() method.**

So, I guess you are fine using **"/"** .

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-contexts.html

Comment: The problem is that its ending with '/' which is the complain that is raised when setting the path to "/". I guess this is some sort of a bug since '/' seams to be a special case then.

Comment: I just noticed that Jetty itself uses "/" as the content path if path.length() == 0.